# Rest Assured Failed to parse the JSON document

Tags: java, junit, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I am trying to test a small rest service that I am doing to study using rest assured. I followed the advice of this guy's video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yDdBOspPp_c

however at the time of realizing the post is said that: failed to parse the json document
However the data is persisted in the database. What should I do?

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Test
    public void deveInserirUmProduto() {

        // Specify base URI
        RestAssured.baseURI = "http://localhost:8080/ProjetoJersey/api/produto";

        // Request Object
        RequestSpecification httpRequest = RestAssured.given();

        //Request playload sending along with post request
        JSONObject requestParams = new JSONObject();

        requestParams.put("nome", "MacBook PRO");
        requestParams.put("tipoProduto", "INFORMATICA");
        requestParams.put("valor", 26000.00);
        requestParams.put("cor", "Cinza Espacial");
        requestParams.put("especificacoes", "Top de linha");

        httpRequest.header("Content-type", "application/json");

        httpRequest.body(requestParams.toJSONString());

        // Response Object
        Response response = httpRequest.request(Method.POST, "/");

        // Print response in console window
        String responseBody = response.getBody().asString();
        System.out.println("Response Body is: " + responseBody);

        // Status code validation
        int statusCode = response.getStatusCode();
        System.out.println("Status code is: " + statusCode);
        Assert.assertEquals(statusCode, 201);

        // Success code validation
        String successCode = response.jsonPath().get("SuccessCode");
        Assert.assertEquals(successCode, "OPERATION_SUCCESS");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Response response = httpRequest.request(Method.POST, "/");
```

In the above line, you only put "/". I think it should be "/register".